# Docker Run MongoDB replica set.., how is it working?

Tags: mongodb, docker, replicaset, testcontainers, mongodb-replica-set

So I'm creating some softwaare that makes heavy use of mongo transactions.
So far, I've tried only with testcontainers mongo, and pure unit testing.
Now I'm moving to test it manually and I get an error that says something like: `Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set ...`, yet that error doesn't happen during unit tests.

I read that this error happens because transactions are only possible on a replica set, but then, how is testcontainers working? I checked `docker ps` during running of tests and only one mongo docker container is up.

I checked the args passed by `testcontainers`, and it resulted they pass `--replSet docker-rs`. So I did, but then I get this error: `NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.`

I'm scratching my head bad, wondering how is testcontainers running a ONE mongo docker container that behaves like a replica set.

Comment: Are you using a `GenericContainer`, the [Testcontainers MongoDB module](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/mongodb/) or [mongodb-replica-set](https://github.com/silaev/mongodb-replica-set/)? Could you please add the relevant parts of your tests that start the MongoDB instance?

Comment: The Testconainers module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using [Tescontainers MongoDB module](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/mongodb/), the missing part in your manual setup is most probably the [mongo replica set initiation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.initiate/).

This is mentioned in the testcontainers module docs as:

> Initialize a single replica set via executing a proper command

Also feel free to take a look at the module sources itself to dig into implementation details. For example, [initReplicaSet() part](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/12b08b9e7ba77fed5d0c5a5665588d1c27338d16/modules/mongodb/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers/MongoDBContainer.java#L78-L81).

Comment: There's nothing missing in the testcontainers part. It works perfectly. What I can't get working is a docker container for transactions (without testcontainers). How does testcontainers do it? Nevermind, you're totally right!

Comment: I dug into the implementation a lot and didn't find that part. I even started checking the source code of ryuk. Guess it just slipped my eyes